# How do you factor $x^2-x-1$?

Tags: quadratics, factoring, quadratic-forms

I know you can't have all integers, but how do you factor this anyway?

Wolfram|Alpha gives me $-\frac{1}{4} (1+\sqrt{5}-2 x) (-1+\sqrt{5}+2 x)$.
Cymath gives me $(x-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})(x-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})$.

The closest I can get is $(x+1)(x-1)-x$.

So how do I get a nice answer like the ones listed above?

Comment: Quadratic formula gives the roots, which is all you need to factor quadratic equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complete the square: Gather $x^2-x$ and whatever constant you need to create something of the form $(x-c)^2$, then repair the changes you've made:
$$
\textstyle x^2-x-1 = \left( x^2-x+\frac14 \right) - \frac14-1 = (x-\frac12)^2-\frac54
$$
Now the RHS has the form $a^2-b^2$ which you can factor as $(a+b)(a-b)$:
$$
\textstyle (x-\frac12)^2-\frac54 = (x-\frac12)^2-(\frac{\sqrt5}2)^2
=(x-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt5}2)(x-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt5}2)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1: If $p$ is a root of $f(x)=x^2-x-1$ then $x-p$ is a factor of $f$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem). So $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)$ where $a,b$ are the roots of $f$ (given by the quadratic formula). This gives Cymath's answer.

If you clear the denominators in Cymath's answer, you get Wolfram's answer.

Solution 2: Complete the square. $x^2-x-1\\=x^2-x+1/4-1-1/4 \\= (x-1/2)^2-5/4$,

which is a difference of squares, so it factors as $(x-1/2-\sqrt {5}/2)(x-1/2+\sqrt5/2)$. This is Cymath's answer.

Comment: How do you know that $(x-a)(x-b)$ where $a,b$ are the roots are factors?

Comment: You have made a minor error

Comment: @JacobWheeler because I know that $x-p$ is a factor if $p$ is a root. This is known as the "remainder theorem" and it states that you divide $f(x)$ by $x-a$ you get remainder $f(a)$. If $a$ is a root, then the remainder of $f(x)/(x-a)$ is $f(a)=0$.

Comment: @Shailesh got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apply quadratic formula for the roots of $x^2-x-1=0$ as follows 
$$x=\frac{-(-1)\pm\sqrt{(-1)^2-4(1)(-1)}}{2(1)}=\frac{1\pm \sqrt 5}{2}$$
hence, one should have the following factors  $$x^2-x-1=1\cdot \left(x-\frac{1+ \sqrt 5}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{1- \sqrt 5}{2}\right)$$
or $$\frac{1}{4}(2x-1-\sqrt 5)(2x-1+\sqrt 5)$$
$$=-\frac{1}{4}(1+\sqrt 5-2x)(-1+\sqrt 5+2x)$$
So both the answers are correct